# Cannot display data from axios response in vue component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

The data retrieve using axios is not displaying on vue eventhough in vue-dev tools there is data in it. Plus i'm getting errors : **[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'logbook_id' of null"** and **TypeError: Cannot read property 'logbook_id' of null**. New in Laravel. Thanks.

[Data retrieved from response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH5tk.png)

**Vue Component**

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h1 v-for="log in logbook" v-bind:key="log.logbook_id" > {{ log.title }} 
</h1>
</div> 
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            logbook:{},
        }
    },
    methods:{
        fetchLog(){
            const url = `/api/logbook/${this.$route.params.id}`;
            axios.get(url).then(response => this.logbook = response.data);
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.');
        this.fetchLog();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $log = logbook::where(['logbook_id' => $id])
    ->first();
    return response($log);
}
```

Comment: You didn't json_encode() it?

Comment: @vivek_23 u mean like this ? return json_encode($log);

Comment: Yes, `json_encode($log);`. That will send the data in JSON format to the client end.

Comment: Also, `response => this.logbook = response.data` should be `(response) => { this.logbook = response.data})` ? Note that if you are using `.data`, you need to make sure that key is added when you are sending response to vue from your server.

Comment: tried both of them, still the same unfortunately. I think the main error is the "Cannot read property 'logbook_id' of null". I'm not sure what that means tho. @vivek_23

Comment: BTW, the data is already been fetched and place in the logbook[] as show in the image.

Comment: Your current code doesn't show your access to logbook_id. Can you show full code?

Comment: you are returning single object not array no need for loop just use `{{ logbook.title }}`

Comment: logbook is array not object,  logbook : [],

Answer (score 0):

You only get back a single logbook object, instead of an array. Your current syntax would work, if you got back an array. The purpose of v-for is commonly to have a list of items, but as you only have one item, there is no purpose in having a list.